# Android: how to keep realmlist updated in the UI

Tags: android, realm

I have a recyclerview which shows a list of students.
All of the students are held in a realmlist in the adapter.

When the user can ask for a data refresh, than the server sends the list of students back to the user.
What i am doing now is to download all of the information from the server , store it in the db , than retrieving it from the database(via realmresults) and than converting the realmresult to realmlist.

My question is how to properly update the UI?
I have seen in the documentation that realmlist have a managed mode where they are updating the ui automatically.. 
What is this managed mode? What does it means?
How do i use the realmlist to keep it in a managed state? 
And what is the right way(aka best practice) to use realmlists?

Note that i cannot hold my information as realmresult directly because im performing some manipulation on the data that i dont want it to be saved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Managed Object vs. Standalone**

The standalone `RealmObject`/`RealmList` is created through the Object's constructor or the `Realm.copyFromRealm()` method. The data accessing in the standalone object won't go through the underline storage engine, instead, it behaves just like normal object. **So the standalone object won't be refreshed when data changes.** Examples for standalone object:

```
MyModel myModel = new MyModel(); // Standalone

MyModel model = realm.where(MyModel.class).findFirst(); // This is managed object.
MyModel standaloneModel = realm.copyFromRealm(model); // The returned value is standalone object.

MyList myList = new MyList(); // Standalone
```

The managed `RealmObject`/`RealmList` are accessing data though Realm's underlying storage engine. They are created when you do query from Realm, or the return from the `copyToRealm()` (and its variant methods). Like:

```
MyModel model = realm.where(MyModel.class).findFirst();

MyModel model = new MyModel(); // This is a standalone object.
model = realm.copyToRealm(modle); // The returned value is managed by Realm now.

MyList myList = realm.where(MyModel.class).findFirst().getMyList();
```

**How to properly update the UI**

The suggestion is using Realm's change listeners. See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications

**And what is the right way(aka best practice) to use `RealmList`?**

This is a bit confusing, but Realm is introducing `RealmCollection` into the next major release (`v0.89.0`). See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2345.

> Note that i cannot hold my information as realmresult directly because im performing some manipulation on the data that i dont want it to be saved.

If the `RealmList` is in managed mode, the data changes will be saved as well. If you don't want some data to be saved, you could consider to use `@Ignore` annotation on those fields. See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#ignoring-properties

---

*Update on 04072016*

**`RealmList` vs. `RealmResults`:**

`RealmList` is a list of `RealmObject` saved as a field of a `RealmObject`. It represents the one-to-many relationship in Realm.

`RealmResults` is the results of query.

Both of them (if `RealmList` in managed-mode) will be auto-refreshed when data changes.

You can get a `RealmResults` from a `RealmList` by [`RealmList.where()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmList.html#where--) like:

```
RealmResults results = myRealmList.where().findAll();
```

---

*This answer will be a bit out-of-date after Realm `v0.89.0` released, because of new [`RealmCollection`](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2345).*

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer! Could you than tell me what is the difference between realmlist and realmresults? If both might change the underlying data, than why should anyone use the realmlist? I mean if i understands correctly, the realmresults are always refreshing my UI, so why should i just use them? What is the difference between realmresults and realmlist? When should we use each one?

Comment: Thank you for the anawer again :) i decided that my best option for now is to use the realmlist, as im usinf the add and remove mmethods alot, something that is not possi le with the realmresults, i hope that realmcollections will also have that method as well. It gives us alot of flexibility to hold different lists at the same time and add new information to them without saving them to the database

Comment: Also, we can not use realmresults as it removes objects from the database once we call remove/clear, and the only way to add objects to the list is by really saving them to the database, will the realmcollection supports adding/removing objects from it without forcing us to save/remove them from the database?

Comment: Right now , if i want to fetch new items from the server and use realmresults, i need to save them to the database, requery to get the results, update the recycleradapter with the new list which force him to reload the list and reset the list items, all of this seems like alot of work to be done if i want to just add a few items to the list.. Or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: "requery to get the results,", the don't have to requery, the results will be updated when the db changed unless you want to change the query conditions. just register a listener, refresh the view. See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2548

Comment: Hm this is strange because when im receiving new data from the server, if im not requerying than the realmresult object dtays with the same size he was before the fetch, i mean i dont get to see the new fetched objects there eithout requerying, with the realmlist i can use the add/addall methods and than just call notifyitemrangechanged, but with the realmresults it only works if im requerying and than call notifydatasetchanged(ehich refresh all of the items in the recyclerview)

Comment: The refresh is triggered by the handler's event. which means it reflects to the current thread in the next event loop. So, try to register a listener and check if the RealmResults changes there.